# Must Rosh HaShannah Simanim be Eaten in a Certain Order?

Tags: minhag, rosh-hashanah-new-year, simanim

Is there a specific minhag regarding when and in what order to eat the simanim? In other words, is it acceptable to serve simanim as a matter of course (leeks with the steak, date cookies for dessert, etc.) or should they be served in their own special time?

Answer (score 2):

The blessings are prioritised (in general, not just on RH). First "Pri ha-etz". Then "Pri ha-adamah". Then "Shehakol". In "Pri ha-etz" priority is given to "7 species" fruits. Within these, the priority is given to the closest to the word "eretz" - land. Thus the priority is olive, date, grape, fig, pomegranate. ["From an article by Rav Eliezer Melamed (in Hebrew)"](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/9115)

Comment: −1. The question was (in part) whether the _siman_ foods must be eaten separately or can be eaten in the course of the meal. Note that no blessing is recited on most foods eaten in the course of a bread meal, which means that this answer does not address the question.

Comment: @msh210 Yet people who eat the simanim before the meal, even after hamotzi, do day berachos because they are not part of the meal.

Comment: @andrewmh20 I have never witnessed anybody say a separate bracha for the simanim other than ha'etz. I believe those would be unnecessary and improper.

Comment: There are siddurim and "Simanim cards" that quite specifically specify ha'adamah and shehakol. This is after kiddush and before hamotzi.

Comment: @Epicentre Ah, yes, I'd forgotten that some eat them before the bread. Nonetheless, this answer is assuming that that's the case and then addressing what order to eat them in, whereas the question was whether in fact there's a specific point that the _siman_ foods are eaten.

Comment: @msh210 The advantage of the practice of doing the simanim before hamotzi is that there is no question re brachot. It also gives a more formal framework. If the simanim are served with the meal, without an additional bracha (but maybe with a "yehi ratzon"), then their symbolic effect is diminished. If they are cooked as part of a dish, then they are even less prominent.

Comment: That last comment sounds kinda like an answer to the question before us. This answer post does not.

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Ish Chai in Parshas Netzavim first year Ois Dales says there is an order and goes through it, but doesn’t explain why that is the order.

The Kaf Hachaim in Orach Chaim 583 ois 25 explains the order that one should do על פי פשט and according to קבלה.